# Concatenating two vectors in R

Tags: r, concatenation

I want to concatenate two vectors one after the other in R. I have written the following code to do it:

```
> a = head(tracks_listened_train)
> b = head(tracks_listened_test)
> a
[1] cc1a46ee0446538ecf6b65db01c30cd8 19acf9a5cbed34743ce0ee42ef3cae3e
[3] 9e7fdbf2045c9f814f6c0bed5da9bed7 3441b1031267fbb6009221bf47f9c5e8
[5] 206c8b79bd02beeea200879afc414879 1a7a95e3845a6815060628e847d14362
18585 Levels: 0001a423baf29add84af6ec58aeb5b90 ...
> b
[1] 7251a7694b79aa9a39f9a1a5f5c8a253 2f362377ef0e7bca112233fdda22a79c
[3] c1196625b1b733b62c43935334e1d190 58e41e462af4185b08231a41453c3faf
[5] 1cc2517fa9c037e02a14ce0950a28f67
10186 Levels: 0001a423baf29add84af6ec58aeb5b90 ...
> res = c(a,b)
> res
[1] 14898  1898 11556  3859  2408  1950  4473  1865  7674  3488  1130
```

However, I get the unexpected result of the resultant vector. What could the problem be?

Comment: You have `factor` class. convert to `character` and then do it i.e. `c(as.character(a), as.character(b))`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We need to convert the `factor` class to `character` class

```
c(as.character(a), as.character(b))
```

---

The reason we get numbers instead of the `character` is based on the storage mode of `factor` i.e. an integer.  So when we do the concatenation, it coerces to the `integer` mode